# Can not clone a git repository over ssh (Bad configuration option)

Tags: ssh, git, openssh

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10, I can not clone my repositories, which are served in Gitlab, over ssh. If I use

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:user_name/repo_name.git
```

command, I get this:

```
~/.ssh/config: line 8: Bad configuration option: Identityfile
~/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I comment `Identityfile` line and run same command, I get this:

```
 debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 /etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 55: Bad configuration option: gssapIauthentication
 /etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 56: Bad configuration option: gssapIdelegatecredentials
 /etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I checked whether `gssapIauthentication` and `gssapIdelegatecredentials` options are default for openssh-client in Ubuntu 16.10 in order to make sure that the error is not related to my tweaking, it turned out that these options are default. In fact, I do not tweak anything in /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

These are the uncommented options in /etc/ssh/ssh_config file:

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

If I command `Identityfile`, `GSSAPIAuthentication`, and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials` options, I can clone my repository over ssh.

Here is my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host gitlab
    Hostname gitlab.com
    RSAAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User user_name
```

openssh_client version:

```
 LC_ALL=C apt-cache policy openssh-client
 openssh-client:
   Installed: 1:7.3p1-1
   Candidate: 1:7.3p1-1
   Version table:
  *** 1:7.3p1-1 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How can I solve this problem? What could cause this problem? Is source of the problem Gitlab?

Thank you in advance.

PS: My native language is not English.

**EDIT**

Although @zwets' answer did not solve the issue, it gave me a hint:

> Could this be a character encoding issue?

So I run command as this:

```
LC_ALL=C git clone git@gitlab.com:user_name/repo_name.git
```

and it worked. But this workaround shows that there is bug in openssh-client package in Ubuntu 16.10. I will open an bug report.

**EDIT2**

I reported a bug in Launchpad and this is the link of report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1638338

Output of `locale` command:

```
locale
LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=tr:en
LC_CTYPE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Output of `sed -n 8p ~/.ssh/config | od -t d1` command:

```
0000000    9   85  115  101  114   32  110  117  109   97  110  100   10
0000015
```

**EDIT3**

Output of `file ~/.ssh/config`

```
/home/numand/.ssh/config: ASCII text
```

`iconv -t ascii -o /dev/null ~/.ssh/config` command returns nothing.

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -V`?

Comment: The bad configs appear to be in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` rather than in your user's `~/.ssh/config` - check there (e.g. `tail /etc/ssh/ssh_config`)

Comment: @muru, `ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Comment: @steeldriver, bad configuration error appears not only in /etc/ssh/ssh_config but in $HOME/.ssh/config, too. The error says this: $HOME/.ssh/config:`line 8: Bad configuration option: Identityfile`. What must I check in /etc/ssh/ssh_config?

Comment: Though the `ssh_config` configuration options are supposed to be case-insensitive, I find it suspicious that precisely the ones with case inversions (Identity**F**ile, **GSSAP**I**A**uthentication, **GSSAPID**elegate**C**redentials) seem to be causing the problem. Could this be a character encoding issue? It shouldn't make a difference but could you try correcting them to 'proper' case?

Comment: Comment out the bad configuration options and you are good.

Comment: @zwets,  I double checked `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `$HOME/.ssh/config` files and all of the options are proper. I do not know why `git` output show them in lower case. I edited my questions with a workaround.

Comment: Is the bug in git or in SSH? Does `ssh git@gitlab.com` work?

Comment: @muru, it does not work. Yes, the bug must be in ssh.

Comment: Just to dig a bit deeper into this apparently locale-related issue. What does `locale` output? And what is the output of `sed -n 8p ~/.ssh/config | od -t d1`? This should give us the byte values of the line containing `Identityfile` that `ssh` chokes on.

Comment: Looks like the issue might be in a different line. What's the output of `file ~/.ssh/config` and `iconv -t ascii -o /dev/null ~/.ssh/config`? That should give us more hints about possible non-ASCII characters. This looks like a collation issue. I remember that the Turkish alphabet contains a variant of the basic Latin `I` with a non-trivial conversion between upper and lower case.